# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable ISSUES

Tags: python, spyder

I coded a tuple code function:

```
coordinates=[(4,5) (80,1) (10,4)]

coordinates=(12)
print(coordinates(1))
```

but it gives me an error like this:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

should I turn the brackets into lists?

Comment: Actually it would give `'int' object is not callable`, unless you've also overwritten `print` with a tuple.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It actually does give the said error, but because of a typo... a missing comma: `[(4,5) (80,1) (10,4)]` between the tuples... Would be easier to understand if the full traceback was posted...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Very good catch. (My earlier comment deleted because I didn't read the question thoroughly enough.)

Comment: @Tomerikoo good spot. OP, this is why a [mre] is helpful.

Comment: This TypeError is generated when `we try to access the tuple as a function`. But since we know tuple is not callable thus the error is raised.

Answer (score 1):

two things are different there from what you might have meant:
for one thing, you wanted to print the first coordinate by calling print(coordinates[1])
but instead tried coordinates(1) which confused python into thinking that you called son func.
for another, you override coordinates there with the line:
coordinates=(12)

Maybe try:

```
coordinates=[(4,5) (80,1) (10,4)]


print(coordinates[1])
```